# php - comparing a string to an array adding the results

Tags: php, string, arraylist

I have a string and an array. I want to compare the words in the string to the array which holds the same words and their value and add the value for all the common words. ie:

```
This is the string:
$check = "red plate fork red plate";

This array is my array:

$arrayItems = array(
        array("name" => "red plate", "price" => 12.00),
        array("name" => "plate", "price" => 8.00),
        array("name" => "blue spoon", "price" => 6.50),
        array("name" => "fork", "price" => 5.75));
```

How can I get the $total which in this case is: `12 + 5.75 + 12 = 29.75`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should be pretty well-documented. Let me know if this is what you wanted:

```
$check = "plate fork plate";

$arrayItems = array(
        array("name" => "plate", "price" => 12.00),
        array("name" => "spoon", "price" => 6.50),
        array("name" => "fork", "price" => 5.75));

$totalPrice = 0;

/*we don't need the extra spaces, just the exact term*/
$checkIsolated = explode(" ", $check); 

foreach ($checkIsolated as $key => $value):

    /*loop through the actual item price list to match whatever */
    /*checkIsolated array holds*/
    foreach ($arrayItems as $itemKey => $itemValue):
        /*a match is found! let's get the corresponding price! :)*/
        if (strstr($itemValue['name'], $value)): 
            $totalPrice += $itemValue['price'];
            continue; /*let's save extra cpu usage here.*/
        endif;
    endforeach;

endforeach;

echo 'Total Price is: ' . $totalPrice;
```

Comment: You're very welcome, glad we could help! If you could just vote that as your preferred answer, that'll be great. It will be of help to others too!

Comment: Vincent Edward Gedaria Binua, I just noticed that I made boo boo! some of the names that I have are made of 2 words, like the "red plate". I forgot about this and now I don't think the code would work properly! so I just edited my question...

Comment: Sorry @Steve, I couldn't quite get it, wouldn't that just fall under plate too?Would you rather revise your question or add a comment for a new test data so we would all see please? Thank you!

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. I just added a line to the question. I have red plate and plate in the array.  also, would it make it easier if make my string comma separated too?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Steve, Yep! If you make your string comma separated, it would be way easier. $checkIsolated = explode(" ", $check) will then become: $checkIsolated = explode(",", $check); Notice that we change it from a space to a comma as separator. Try that and see if it works!

Comment: I comma separated my string and changed this part to this: $checkIsolated = explode(", ", $check); and it's working fine!

Comment: sweet! make sure to trim the needle- 2nd parameter on strstr function- you'll never know when those extra spaces squeeze in! :)

Answer (score 0):

@Steve you can do like this.

```
$str = "plate,fork,red plate";
$strArr = explode(",", $str);
$arr = array(array( "name" => 'red plate', "price" => '50'),array( "name" => 'plate', "price" => '50'),array( "name" => 'fork', "price" => '25'));
$total = 0;
foreach ($strArr as $key => $value){
   foreach ($arr as $arrkey => $arrvalue){
      if (strstr($arrvalue['name'], $value)){
         $total = $total + $arrvalue['price'];
      }
   }
}

echo $total;
```

Comment: PHP Weblineindia, thank you for your help! however I just responded to Vincent too as following: I just noticed that I made boo boo! some of the names that I have are made of 2 words, like the "red plate". I forgot about this and now I don't think the code would work properly! so I just edited my question...

Comment: @Steve with comma separated you can do with above new edited code